# Why does `testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly` take so long to run?

Tags: android, junit

When running android test cases why does `testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly` take so long when (I think) all it is doing is checking the `Context`? It seems to take anywhere from 10 to 20 seconds.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: Trying to delete this . . . I had a `setUp` method that was taking the bulk of the time

Comment: Post your solution. Answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Android Source here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/donut-release/core/java/android/test/AndroidTestCase.java.

Here is the source:

```
public void testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly() {
    assertNotNull("Context is null. setContext should be called before tests are run",
            mContext);        
}
```

All it is doing is asserting not `null`. I am pretty sure it must be some of your other test cases that are taking a while.

Empty, but the official docs are here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html#testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly().